# php htaccess url encode/decode remove trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using `.htaccess` to remove trailing slash from URI:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

The website is built with `Codeigniter` and has three languages, where russian is one of them, that uses cyrillic chars in URI.I use `urlencode` for generating routes and `urldecode` to find the right page from database by URI.

Removing trailing slash works fine with english and german languages, but when I try add trailing slash to URI where cyrillic chars are used, I get 404 page. URI after removing `/` seems correct, but I can't understand why I get 404, the URL is the same as entered without trailing slash.

Comment: You need to use rawurldecode and rawurlencode - check [PHP documentacion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, tried it before `anubhava` answer, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NE` flag for not encoding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=301,L,NE]
```